# Devising Excel Spreadsheet Formulas

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, spreadsheet, accounting

I'm using Excel for the accounting purposes of a group venture, to keep track of our expenses, costs, payments, and balances.

- Details of each expense are stored in columns `A:J`
- Total costs and balances are stored in columns `K:M`
- Payments and dates are stored in columns `N:S`

[image]

*Generally speaking,* I'm responsible for **34%** of the cost of *most expenses,* whereas each other party is responsible for **22%** of the cost of *most expenses.* This is the case for the majority of expenses.

However, there are a few expenses that I would like to split only between specific parties – `J2`, `J9`, and `J10` – which are emphasized by a green, bold font in the screenshot above.

Understanding the **parties** column:

- `1111` (me, alex, nan, nate)
- `1100` (me, alex)
- `1000` (me)
- `0101` (alex, nate)
- et cetera

I'm not sure how to go about this, therefore I have a few questions:

1. Is there a formula to ignore certain values in a row based on other values in the same row? For example, is there a way for the **collective total cost** formula, `=SUM(H:H)`, to ignore `H2`, `H9`, and `H10`, other than something like `=SUM(H3:H8,H11:H99999)`?
2. Conversely, is there a formula to select every value in the `H` column whose value in the `J` column is equal to `1100` for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use either of the formulas,

`=SUMIF(J:J,"1100",H:H)`

or even this one

`=SUMPRODUCT(($J$2:$J$17="1100")*($H$2:$H$17))`

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

Comment: I will test tomorrow when I wake up and get back to you!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help man!

Comment: Glad to help you @BugWhisperer ,, keep asking ☺

Comment: do you know if in *Excel 2010* there is any way to sum amounts in a column if the color of the font is a particular color? Or just do things in general based on the color of text?

Comment: Yes I do @BugWhisperer,, on the basic of Font/Color & even back ground color SUM  as well as few other functions can be used .

Comment: Can you give me an example of how a command/formula would be composed? I tried earlier and couldn't get it to work in the **Excel 2010**

Comment: You there Rajesh?

Comment: @BugWhisperer,,  either [Edit] your post & add a caveat that you are in need of something new, or better post a new question,, and just prompt me using comments. Since post any CODE or even Formula/ Method is not possible as comments and is against norms of the community.

Comment: I will do that. Thanks Rajesh